# How to use Column in NestedScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to use nestedScrollView on my page and my problem is children of the column do not scroll completely. For example, here, the flutter logo must be scroll completely up, But part of it remains on the page:

[image: screenshot]

this is my code:

```
NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        new SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          title: new Text('Flutter Demo'),
        ),
      ];
    },
    body: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        FlutterLogo(size: 200,),
        wItemList(context)
      ],
    ),
  )
```

How can I fully scroll all column's children?

Answer (score 0):

For child ListView, use that parameter:

```
 shrinkWrap: true,
 physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: it doesn't affect my app

Comment: try physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics